# How to change format of dataset using tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, dataset, data-manipulation

Is there an efficient way to deal with datasets using tensorflow library? I would like to manipulate them, like delete columns/rows, edit them etc.

Comment: Do you mean numpy array? What's wrong with using pandas?

Comment: Actually i am a totally newbie and i didnt know how to deal with reading datasets in python and i was asking if there is a quick and efficient way to do it via tensorflow,but as I checked pandas should do my job as @Maxim mentions

Comment: Read the docs please

Answer (score 0):

This sample code should help you get started with importing a CSV, doing some basic manipulations and running NN learning in tensorflow. You can get the [data here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales/data).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# Read and manipulate data from CSV
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df = df.dropna(how='any')
df = df.drop('DayOfWeek', axis=1)
df.Customers = df.Customers / 1000.0
df.CompetitionDistance = df.CompetitionDistance / 1000.0
df.Sales = df.Sales / 1000.0

# Parameters
features = 2
hidden = 3
learning_rate = 0.2

# Prepare input and output arrays
train_x = np.array(df[['CompetitionDistance', 'Customers']])
train_y = np.array(df[['Sales']]).reshape([-1])

# Build a simple TF graph
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, features], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name='y')
W = tf.get_variable(name='W', shape=[features, hidden])
b = tf.get_variable(name='b', shape=[hidden], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
z = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
predict = tf.reduce_sum(z, axis=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - predict))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Run the training
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in xrange(101):
    _, loss_value = session.run([optimizer, loss], 
                                feed_dict={x: train_x, y: train_y})
    if i % 10 == 0:
      print "epoch=%03i, loss=%.5f" % (i, loss_value)
```